# Haskell IO create a list of strings and display it

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, io

I'm trying to write a program that allows the user to build up a list of strings by entering them in one at a time, and displays the list after every step.

Here is my code so far:

```
buildList :: [String] -> IO ()
buildList arr = do
    putStr "Enter a line:"
    str <- getLine
    if str == "" then
        return ()
    else do
        let newarr = arr : str
        putStrLn ("List is now: " ++ newarr)
        buildList newarr


listBuilder :: IO ()
listBuilder = do
    buildList []
```

`listBuilder` is starting the list by passing in the empty list, and I'm trying to use recursion so that the code keeps running until the user enters the empty string.

Its not working, any ideas welcome

Here is a desired input:

```
Enter a line: hello
List is now ["hello"]
Enter a line: world
List is now ["hello","world"]
Enter a line:
```

Error:

```
Couldn't match type `Char' with `[String]'
Expected type: [[String]]
  Actual type: String
In the second argument of `(:)', namely `str'
In the expression: arr : str
In an equation for `newarr': newarr = arr : str
```

EDIT:

This fixed it, thanks to the clues and use of `show`

```
buildList :: [String] -> IO ()
buildList arr = do
    putStr "Enter a line:"
    str <- getLine
    if str == "" then
        return ()
    else do
        let newarr = arr++[str]
        putStrLn ("List is now: " ++ show newarr)
        buildList newarr


listBuilder :: IO ()
listBuilder = do
    buildList []
```

Comment: It's not only not working, it's **not compiling**. You nearly got it, though; My suggestion would be to rename second `arr` to something like `newarr` or `arr'` to avoid confusion and name clashes.

Comment: this is correct, I'm quite stuck!

Comment: Read the compiler error again. It's trying to help you. Anyway, it took me really a few minor fixes to get it working, so I'll leave it as an exercise. Post an answer when you're done `:)`

Comment: When you're asking for help with a program that doesn't compile, always include the compiler error. Now implement Bartek's suggestion and recompile. If you still get compiler errors you don't understand, post the corrected code and the error message.

Comment: Man, I've been looking at it for like two hours now, I don't think its going to click! `Couldn't match type 'Char' with '[String]'Expected type: [[String]] Actual type: String`. how do you fix it?

Comment: @benharris Well done.

Comment: if it said `Couldn't match type 'Char' with '[String]'
Expected type: [[String]]
  Actual type:  [Char]` perhaps it would be much easier for you to see the problem. `String` is the same as `[Char]`, and this message *assumes* you already know that. That's a bad message, not helpful. :) It is inconsistent: talks about `Char` but replaces `[Char]` with `String`. Confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this working by

(a) putting the new string at the end of the list with `arr++[str]` instead of `arr:str` since `:` can only be used like `singleThing:list`,
 (b) splitting the run-round into a separate function, and
 (c) passing the result on with `return` so you can use it elsewhere in your program

```
buildList arr = do
    putStrLn "Enter a line:"
    str <- getLine
    if str == "" then
        return arr
    else do
        tell (arr++[str])

tell arr = do
        putStrLn ("List is now: " ++ show arr) -- show arr to make it a String
        buildList arr
```

giving

```
Enter a line:
Hello
List is now: ["Hello"]
Enter a line:
world
List is now: ["Hello","world"]
Enter a line:

done
```

Comment: Don't forget to check out [Gabriel Gonzalez' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21792654/1598537); it's very much worth learning pipes, and here's as good a place as any to start - you've struck gold getting that answer from one of Haskell's leading lights.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this problem more declaratively using the `pipes` and `foldl` libraries:

```
import Control.Foldl (purely, list)
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P

main = runEffect $ P.stdinLn >-> purely P.scan list >-> P.print
```

You can read this as a pipeline:

- `P.stdinLn` is a source of lines input by the user
- `P.scan` behaves like `Data.List.scanl`, except for pipelines instead of lists.  `purely P.scan list` says to continuously output the values seen so far.
- `P.print` prints these output lists to the console

Here's an example of this pipeline in action:

```
$ ./example
[]
Test<Enter>
["Test"]
ABC<Enter>
["Test","ABC"]
42<Enter>
["Test","ABC","42"]
<Ctrl-D>
$
```

You can also easily switch out other ways to fold the lines just by changing the argument to `purely scan`.  For example, if you switch out `list` with `Control.Foldl.vector` then it will output vectors of lines instead of lists.

To learn more, you can read the documentation for the [pipes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.0.2/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html) and [foldl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.0.2/docs/Control-Foldl.html) libraries.

Comment: you meant `Data.List.scanl1` perhaps?

Comment: Yeah, I meant `scanl` (no 1).  I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `:` data constructor can only be used to append an element to the beginning of the list. When you write `let arr=arr:str`, you are using it to put an element at the end of the list.  Instead, you can either construct your list backwards like this `let arr=str:arr` or use the `++` operator to append it to the end of the list like this `let arr=arr++[str]`.